# Spring + Hibernate + Annotation + XmlWebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

When Tomcat starts I get this messages:

```
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
2012-06-20 17:02:55,209 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started>
2012-06-20 17:02:55,243 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - <Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Wed Jun 20 17:02:55 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy>
2012-06-20 17:02:55,305 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]>



2012-06-20 17:02:56,094 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - <Bean 'hibernateConfiguration' of type [class com.xxxxxxxxxx.android.market.config.HibernateConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$53f79727] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)>
2012-06-20 17:02:56,690 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] - <Building new Hibernate SessionFactory>
2012-06-20 17:02:57,285 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] - <Updating database schema for Hibernate SessionFactory>
2012-06-20 17:02:57,621 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - <Bean 'sessionFactoryBean' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)>


2012-06-20 17:02:57,694 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@46ed5d9d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,beanConfiguration,hibernateConfiguration,AppService,appController,homeController,jspViewResolver,messageSource,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,appCategory,appDAO,appReleaseDAO,appService,sessionFactoryBean,transactionManager,persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy>
2012-06-20 17:02:58,011 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - <Mapped URL path [/{id}] onto handler 'appController'>
2012-06-20 17:02:58,012 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - <Mapped URL path [/{id}.*] onto handler 'appController'>
2012-06-20 17:02:58,012 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - <Mapped URL path [/{id}/] onto handler 'appController'>
2012-06-20 17:02:58,012 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] - <Root mapping to handler 'homeController'>
2012-06-20 17:02:58,482 INFO [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 3273 ms>
Jun 20, 2012 5:02:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jun 20, 2012 5:02:58 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jun 20, 2012 5:02:58 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/122  config=null
Jun 20, 2012 5:02:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4237 ms
```

Here is my Hibernate config class. It's annotated based and when I use inside of the Junit tets @ContextConfiguration all works.

```
    package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;

import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.xxx;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.xxx;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.xxx;

@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "philipp");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Market");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "philipp");

        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { xxx.class, xxx.class, xxx.class });
        bean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        bean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

My spring-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- eingefügt aus app-context -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.config" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.market.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.service.app" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.controller" />
    <!-- eingefügt aus app-context -->

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Now, when will get some items by rest-api from the database I get this:

```
    org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:685)
    com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.AppDAOImpl.currentSession(AppDAOImpl.java:22)
    com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.AppDAOImpl.getAppById(AppDAOImpl.java:46)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy21.getAppById(Unknown Source)
    com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.service.app.AppServiceImpl.getAppById(AppServiceImpl.java:29)
    com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.controller.AppController.getApp(AppController.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:574)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)



    package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.App;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.service.app.AppService;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private AppService appService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getApp(@PathVariable int id) {
        App app = appService.getAppById(id);
        return new ModelAndView("appXmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX
                + "app", app);
    }
}




    package com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.service.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.App;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.AppDAO;

@Service("AppService")
public class AppServiceImpl implements AppService {

    @Autowired
    private AppDAO appDAO;

    public boolean saveApp(App app) {
        return appDAO.insert(app);
    }

    public void deleteApp(App app) {
        appDAO.delete(app);

    }

    public void updateApp(App app) {
        appDAO.update(app);
    }

    @Transactional
    public App getAppById(int id) {
        return appDAO.getAppById(id);
    }

    public App getAppByName(String name) {
        return appDAO.getAppByName(name);
    }

}




import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.App;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.AppCategory;
import com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.android.market.dao.AppRelease;
```

New HibernateConfiguration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", MySQL5InnoDBDialect.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "philipp");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/BusinessMarket");
        props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "philipp");

        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean bean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { AppCategory.class, App.class, AppRelease.class });
        bean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        bean.setExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory(false);
        bean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Comment: Error does not come from this $Proxy21, wich is a generated class. Your error comes from Hibernate configuration : `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread` . Do you use multithreading, or thread pooling in this particular case ? As well, do you specify a correct MySQL port (3306 by default) ?

Comment: I use default stuff and when I run it with Junit tests everything works fine.

Comment: Can we see AppServiceImpl and AppController please?

Comment: Now I added 
props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread"); and get org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction

Comment: @Alex I add the two files to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Spring 3.1 Configuration in Java try removing

`<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

and specifying @EnableTransactionManagement on `HibernateConfiguration` as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration
```

Comment: I removed <tx:...> from the app-context.xml and add @@EnableTransactionManagement

I also add bean.setExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory(false);
Now I get this error: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

I add the new hibernate config at the end of my inital post.

Comment: I add @Transaction to the Method in AppServiceImpl and now it works :-) thx!

Comment: Glad it helped. You haven't specified how you load your @Configuration class and the XML file but I suspect that there is some problem with specifying your transaction manager in Java and enabling annotation driven transaction management in the XML. Is one part of your root context and one part of your dispatcher context?

Comment: Umm, did this stop being the answer? If so care to explain why. If you have another question ask it elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry. Removing it was a fault.